# Passing Custom Types to an Apollo Mutation

Tags: types, middleware, graphql, typing, apollo

Is there a way to pass a custom GraphQL Type with Apollo ?

e.g. : like the below, a Mutation to create an User (Custom User Type is already defined in the GraphQL schema) :

```
createUser(user: User): String
```

I think that we're only allowed to pass Primary Types, so no Object.
Another option (not clean), would be to serialize an Object as a String and pass it as a String parameter, and in the resolver to deserialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass an object in a mutation. See for example this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet). But you have to define an extra input user GraphQL type and cannot use the user type.

In your case it could look like this:

```js
`
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  // other query properties
}

input UserInput {
  username: Strin!
}
`
```

And the mutation and the resolver could look like this:

```js
`
mutation createUser(user: UserInput!): String
`

Mutation: {
  createUser(_, { user }) {
    // create in database
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that was exactly what I was missing.